# AndroidX camera - ERROR_CAMERA_IN_USE while in OPENING state

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, android-jetpack-compose

I have a camera view inside a Jetpack Compose screen using Androidx.camera version 1.3.1.

My code is a copy from the original android developer site "Concurrent use cases": https://developer.android.com/media/camera/camerax/architecture#combine-use-cases

I am testing it on 2 physical (Android 13 and 11) and one Virtual (Android 14) devices.

But it does not work on the Android 11 one. (It is an industrial "PDA with RFID reader X6" many of our clients and partners use in the industry: https://www.directindustry.com/prod/shenzhen-swell-technology-company-limited/product-234583-2395196.html)

All I see is a black screen and a long reoccurring Debug message list in the Logcat every 2 seconds:

```
{Camera@83395df[id=0]} Attempting to force open the camera.
tryOpenCamera(Camera@83395df[id=0]) [Available Cameras: 0, Already Open: true (Previous state: OPENING)] --> SUCCESS
Recalculating open cameras:
    Camera                                       State                 
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Camera@a5b0518[id=1]                         UNKNOWN               
    Camera@83395df[id=0]                         OPENING               
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Open count: 1 (Max allowed: 1)
{Camera@83395df[id=0]} Cancelling scheduled re-open: androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback$ScheduledReopen@c510771
{Camera@83395df[id=0]} Opening camera.
{Camera@83395df[id=0]} Transitioning camera internal state: REOPENING --> OPENING
New public camera state CameraState{type=OPENING, error=null} from OPENING and null
Publishing new public camera state CameraState{type=OPENING, error=null}
All use case: [androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-90aa6c79-134a-48df-a980-d2ebadc6072d59110889, androidx.camera.core.Preview-3e8abec0-7c14-4284-88d4-f44991fa985d204268142] for camera: 0
CameraService::connect call (PID -1 "com.xxxxx.xxxxxxx", camera ID 0) for HAL version default and Camera API version 2
{Camera@83395df[id=0]} Unable to open camera due to CAMERA_IN_USE (4): connectHelper:1462: Higher-priority client using camera, ID "0" currently unavailable
CameraDevice.onError(): 0 failed with ERROR_CAMERA_IN_USE while in OPENING state. Will attempt recovering from error.
Attempt to reopen camera[0] after error[ERROR_CAMERA_IN_USE]
{Camera@83395df[id=0]} Transitioning camera internal state: OPENING --> REOPENING
New public camera state CameraState{type=OPENING, error=StateError{code=2, cause=null}} from OPENING and StateError{code=2, cause=null}
Publishing new public camera state CameraState{type=OPENING, error=StateError{code=2, cause=null}}
{Camera@83395df[id=0]} Resetting Capture Session
{Camera@83395df[id=0]} Releasing session in state REOPENING
{Camera@83395df[id=0]} CameraDevice.onClosed()
{Camera@83395df[id=0]} Camera closed due to error: ERROR_CAMERA_IN_USE
```

It basically says the camera is already opened by some other process.
I have all other application closed, and my code is only called 1x, so I found no issue that my app would not unbind from the camera provider or something.

What may cause this issue and how can I resolve so I have a camera live view in my app.

Additional info:
when using the system `ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()` the "system" camera view is opened and I able to take pictures, but due to the lack of control over it it is not a solution for my application.